# How to insert ' in DB using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate for all DB operations.

My problem is that, I want to insert an string in table which contains `'` e.g. `rea9'ea/rea9'ea`. 
While inserting it I'm getting the following exception

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ea/rea9','6a8b2622d3b8ab7de31c0e2496cef2bd',5840,'')' at line 1 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554) at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2046)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1949)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:165)
    ... 8 more
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Would help to see the code that's doing the insert.  Seems like your string isn't getting escaped, but Hibernate should handle that for you automatically.  The fact that it isn't makes me think you must be doing something funny in your code.

Comment: Please show the code that your using!

Comment: I'm writing hql for it. I simply creates the hql and fire the query.
Nothing for fun. I guess it's like inserting unicode string in table.

Comment: Now we all know the OP's password... ;-)

Comment: Looks like you are generating your query by hand.

Comment: Hey what's this bounty?
I don't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

First, have you mapped your table to a POJO? This is, of course, the heart of what makes Hibernate so powerful. If you have, then inserting any String is easy:

```
MyPOJO m = new MyPOJO();
m.setName("asdf'!@#$%^&*()\"1234567890");
HibernateUtil.currentSession().save(m);
```

If you need to include any string in an HQL statement, then it should be a parameter:

```
HibernateUtil.currentSession().createQuery("from MyTable where Name=:name")
            .setParameter("name","asdf'!@#$%^&*()\"1234567890")
            .list();
```